# Python Generator Indexing Optimization

Tags: python, generator

Let's say I have a generator that I want to pull the 10th element from but ignore the first 9.  The generator is a function I've written that looks something like this:

```
def myGenerator(arg1, arg2):
    for i in arg1:
        myState = doSomeWork(i, arg2)
        yield expensiveOperation(myState)
```

Now I can use it and grab the 10th index out of it like this:

```
myGen = myGenerator(list1, list2)
tenthElement = next(itertools.islice(myGen,10,11))
```

I'm wondering if this runs `expensiveOperation` ten times, or just once?
(EDIT: it calls it 10 times, but this next part is what I'm interested in.)
Is there any way to optimize away the other 9 calls to `expensiveOperation` since they are discarded? (edited for clarity)

I can think of several other solutions that don't involve using a generator function and would give exactly what I want, but the syntax isn't as clean as just turning an iterative function into a generator by replacing `return` with `yield`.

EDIT:
I'm not necessarily trying to solve this specific problem so much as looking for a way to inexpensively "scroll" a generator.  In the real case I'm currently working with, I don't actually know which index I want when I call `myGenerator` for the first time.  I may grab the 15th index, then the 27th, then the 82nd.  I could probably figure a way to slice to the 15th on the first call, but then I need to scroll 12 more the next time around.

Comment: Can you add the `islice` functionality to `myGenerator`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generator is isolated from its consumer -- it doesn't know what is being throw away.  So, yes, it does the expensive operation at every step.

I would just move the expensive operation outside the generator:

```
def myGenerator(arg1, arg2):
    for i in arg1:
        myState = doSomeWork(i, arg2)
        yield myState

myGen = myGenerator(list1, list2)
tenthElement = expensiveOperation(next(itertools.islice(myGen,10,11)))
```

Comment: "myGenerator" is in a low level utility file.  Exposing "expensiveOperation" to the high level code would break encapsulation I would rather preserve.  But I COULD return a lambda... I'd never thought of a lambda producing generator before...

Comment: @Mike: Alternatively, return an instance of a custom proxy class with a specified interface if you need something more elaborate than returning a callable.  You'd only expose the interface of your proxy class.

Comment: Using lambdas for deferred operations is a good general purpose pattern whenever the cost of creating the lambda is less than the cost of the expensiveOperation.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way for python to know that the expensive operation can be skipped. For example, it might have side effects that need to happen. So there is no way of fast-forwarding a generator.

One option:

```
def myGenerator(arg1, arg2):
    for i in arg1:
        myState = doSomeWork(i, arg2)
        yield functools.partial(expensiveOperation, myState)
```

This will return a callable object instead of the actual value. To get the actual value, you call the yielded value. Only then will the expensive operations be performed.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what happens:

```
def expensive_operation(x):
    print 'expensive operation', x
    return x

def myGenerator():
    for i in xrange(1000):
        yield expensive_operation(i)

myGen = myGenerator()
tenthElement = next(itertools.islice(myGen,10,11))
print 'tenthElement', tenthElement
```

prints

```
expensive operation 0
expensive operation 1
expensive operation 2
expensive operation 3
expensive operation 4
expensive operation 5
expensive operation 6
expensive operation 7
expensive operation 8
expensive operation 9
expensive operation 10
tenthElement 10
```

Best would be to decouple `expensiveOperation` from `myGenerator` since your code suggests that `expensiveOperation` does not affect `myState`.

```
def myGenerator(arg1, arg2):
    for i in arg1:
        myState = doSomeWork(i, arg2)
        yield myState
```

Then apply the `expensiveOperation` only when you want it.

Comment: Yes, as soon as I posted the question I actually went off to test it just like this.  That makes the first "question" in my post rhetorical, but the second question "can I avoid it without a total rewrite" is what I'm really after.

Comment: @MikeEdwards:  You'll need to rewrite the generator at least.

Answer (score 0):

Generators are meant to be consumed one item at a time.  While it takes more work to create, what you should be using in your case is an iterable:

```
class myIterable():
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        myState = doSomeWork(self.arg1[index], self.arg2)
        return expensiveOperation(myState)

myIter = myIterable(list1, list2)
tenthElement = myIter[10]
```

You'll need to add more code to `__getitem__` if you want to support slices and negative indexing.